# Custom authorize attribute based on application settings

Tags: c#, configuration, authorize-attribute

Context: C# ASP.NET MVC Web Application.

I added functionality which enables me to impersonate another user.
I should only see this functionality when the application is configured as such. So I added to the appSettings in web.config.

```
<add key="AllowImpersonation" value="true" />
```

(Not) Showing the controls is easy. But I also want to disable the corresponding controller method.

First thing on my mind is a custom [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) in which I can  just check for the configuration setting.

Even better would be a more generic attribute in which you can provide the key of the (boolean) Appsetting to check. Something like this:

```
namespace MILF.Security
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class ConfigSetting_Authorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private string _configKey;

        public ConfigSetting_Authorize(string configKey)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(configKey))
                throw new ArgumentException("configKey");
            this._configKey = configKey;
        }

        //Core authentication, called before each action
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            try         
            {   
                return Convert.ToBoolean(AppSettingsHelper.Get<bool>(this._configKey))
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        //Called when access is denied
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            SecurityLogManager securityLogManager = new SecurityLogManager(filterContext);
            var message = string.format("{0} triez to access shit that waz disabled.", filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            securityLogManager.Write(message);
            securityLogManager = null;
        }
    }
}

namespace MILF.Utils
{
    public static class AppSettingsHelper
    {
        public static T Get<T>(string key)
        {
            var appSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appSetting)) throw new Exception(key);

            var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
            return (T)(converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(appSetting));
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
public class ImpersonateController : BaseController
{
    // GET: Impersonate
    [ConfigSetting_Authorize("AllowImpersonation")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (!LoggedInUser.IsAdministrator)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View(new List<KBEAccounts.Account>());
    }   

    [ConfigSetting_Authorize("AllowImpersonation")]
    public ActionResult Impersonate(string Id)
    {
        if (!LoggedInUser.IsAdministrator)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        // Set the account to impersonate
        var service = new ActiveDirectoryUsersService();

        this.LoggedInUser =
            service.GetUserByLoginNameToImpersonate(
                Id,
                (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LoggedInUser.ImpersonatorPersonnelId)) ?
                    LoggedInUser.EmployeeNumber :
                    LoggedInUser.ImpersonatorPersonnelId,
                (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LoggedInUser.ImpersonatorCommonName)) ?
                    LoggedInUser.CommonName :
                    LoggedInUser.ImpersonatorCommonName,
                (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LoggedInUser.ImpersonatorFullName)) ?
                    LoggedInUser.FullName :
                    LoggedInUser.ImpersonatorFullName);

        // redirect to home
        return RedirectToAction("", "");
    }       

}
```

But it feels like I am re-inventing the wheel. 
[image]

**Does the .NET framework not already supply this functionality?**

Comment: Why not just an action filer attribute...just save the configuration value in `session` and just check for the Boolean...and decorates the methods on the controller with your attribute and that's it...makes sense?

Comment: @Hackerman: I have no idea. Can you show me?

Comment: Check this article(the info is a little bit old), but check the info about the `OnActionExecuted` event, that way you can control the flow and check things first...if the Boolean is not present you can build a little logic in order to disallow access to the controller method....remember, `ActionFilterAttribute` plus `OnActionExecuted`...go Tony go :)

Comment: @Hackerman: 'OnActionExecuted' the whole idea is that I do not want actions to be executed when the configuration to allow it is not there.

Comment: I assume that you have two comments...the first one, before reading the docs...and the last one, post reading the docs xD

Comment: I forgot the link to the article: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs